# Expo cancel or delete a scheduled notification from server

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-notifications

I need to cancel a scheduled notification sent from my backend server with the [expo-server-sdk-node](https://github.com/expo/expo-server-sdk-node), because it’s a reminder notification about a scheduled appointment that can be canceled by the appointment’s service provider, but the expo-server-sdk-node doesn't have any function to delete a notification.

I also thought about checking if the appointment is not canceled before alerting the user, but expo does not have a event to handle notifications received in background.

Is there any workaround I can do without ejecting my app? Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Asked the same question at expo's forum and charliecruzan from Expo Team answered:

"You can’t cancel a remote push notification, but you can cancel local scheduled notifications. If you want to run code before your app shows a remote push notification that it’s received, then you’ll need to eject"